# Image src is not working when using nodemailer

Tags: node.js

Every time a user is registered to my website, I would like to send an automatic email to him with 
 the logo of the company, this is how I did it but for some reason, the IMG doesn't show.

```
       mailSender.sendEmail('donotreplay@example.co.il','example@mail.com', " Hey " 
       +userToCreate.ownerName+" , Welcome to Example", 

       `
       <table>

       <tr style="background:black"> <img src="img/logo.png"></tr>
       <tr>Check If Image Works</tr>

       </table>
        `        
        )
```

Comment: what library do you use ?

Comment: @MaieonBrix nodemailer

Comment: You should probably use absolute path to image in img.src

Comment: Can you look at here : https://blog.mailtrap.io/sending-emails-with-nodemailer/

Answer (score 3):

in nodemailer configuration you must set attachment, example:

```
from: '"Orange Water" <123@orange.com>', // sender address
to: getEmail,  // list of receivers
subject: subject,
html: data, // html body
attachments: [{
filename: 'image.png',
path: 'your path to image',
cid: 'unique@kreata.ee' //same cid value as in the html img src
}]
});
```

And in your html file, img src must the same cid which already declared in nodemailer configuration. example:

```
<p<img src="cid:unique@kreata.ee" width="100" height="100" </p>
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the full URL of the image in the src attribute.

`<tr style="background:black"> <img src="https://yourdomain.com/img/logo.png"></tr>`

Comment: So if i'm on localhost right now should I write it like this:
             <img src="http://localhost:3001/img/logo.png">  ??